# Installing Kentico CMS as 3 tier

Tags: deployment, kentico, 3-tier

I need to work with a client whose web hosting insisted on having a database sql, application server and a web server.

The Kentico documentations did say that it is a 3 tier application but I couldn't find information on how to deploy it as such.

How does one install the Kentico CMS (v11) as a 3 tier Application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kentico + MVC, you can get a 3 tier application.  If you're developing using Kentico's Portal or Portal + ASPX method, you will not get a true 3 tier application setup.

[This is an old thread](https://devnet.kentico.com/forums?forumid=13&threadid=1004) I reference but user wtijsma's first response explains the setup of Kentico and the reason it's not a true 3 tier application.  Back then Kentico wasn't even thinking of MVC so it wasn't even an issue or option.